# UIFont.systemFontOfSize with weight before iOS 8.2

Tags: ios, swift, uifont

I need to use `UIFont.systemFontOfSize(10, weight: UIFontWeightLight)` on iOS 8.0, but it's only available from iOS 8.2.

What's a good workaround?

Comment: `systemFontOfSize:weight` is available in iOS8.2 and above and below u need use `UIFontDescriptor`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this

use  `respondsToSelector` for find the method is available or not :

```
    let currentFont: UIFont
    if UIFont.respondsToSelector("systemFontOfSize:weight:") {
        print("TRUE")
        currentFont = .systemFontOfSize(10, weight: UIFontWeightLight)
    }
    else {
        print("FALSE")
        currentFont = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Light", size: 10)!
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

Use the `#available` expression for checking OS version.

```
if #available(iOS 8, *) {
    // Add your API code for iOS 8
} else {
    // Add your API code for below iOS 8
}
```